# Update or create async Django ORM instance

Tags: django, asynchronous

As the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/) states, it supports async using a custom interface, with methods like `get` being `aget`. I'm trying to save my instances using `update_or_create` method and I was wondering how can I convert this to an async context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django 4.1 async ORM interface also supports methods like `update_or_create`. Its definition follows the same logic, it is called `aupdate_or_create`.